# Using OR operand in a Swift ternary operator

Tags: ios, swift, ternary-operator

How can I use OR in a ternary operator? Here's what I'm trying to do:

`let surname = name == "John" || "Jack" ? "Johnson" : "Smith"`

Comment: let surname = (name == "John" ||  name ==  "Jack") ? "Johnson" : "Smith"

Comment: `("John" || "Jack")` - wouldn't that work?

Comment: Related: [How to compare one value against multiple values - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750139/how-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use brackets, and add `name ==` in your second comparison condition, As I put first in comment this is the appropriated code

```
let surname = (name == "John" ||  name ==  "Jack") ? "Johnson" : "Smith"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Use brackets:

```
let surname = (name == "John" || name == "Jack") ? "Johnson" : "Smith"
```

These brackets are necessary because you want to evaluate first if `name` is either *John* or *Jack* before "passing" that result to the ternary operator.

Additionally, like in a all C-like languages, you have to mention `name` twice, unlike the example code in your question, in order to compare it with "John" and "Jack".

If you want to avoid naming *name* twice, you can write instead:

```
let surname = ["John", "Jack"].contains(name) ? "Johnson" : "Smith"
```

The latter makes use of the `contains()` function of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively

```
let surname = ["John", "Jack"].contains(name) ? "Johnson" : "Smith"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware of **Operator precedence**

You should use brackets to form valid condition.

```
let surname = (name == "John" ||  name ==  "Jack") ? "Johnson" : "Smith"
```

Answer (score 1):

Except for brackets, you can also use array.contains for cases with a lot of names that could make the bracket code long and unreadable.

```
let name = "Three"
let nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "John", "Jack", "Vlatko"]
let surname = ["John", "Jack"].contains(name) ? "Johnson" : "Smith"
let surnameAlternate = nameList.contains(name) ? "Johnson" : "Smith"
```