# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Bool'

Tags: swift, boolean-expression

I am trying to write a function that will return true if the String str starts with a vowel.  the following code will compile fine

```
func beginsWithVowel(str: String) -> Bool {
    if(str.characters.count == 0){
        return false
    } else if(str.characters[str.startIndex] == "a"){
        return true
    }
    return false
}
beginsWithVowel(str: "apple")
```

the problem is when I compare the first character to more than one character, for example

```
else if(str.characters[str.startIndex] == "a" || "e" || "i")
```

then I get the error 'Cannot convert the value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Bool''

I've been fiddling with the code but no luck so far, any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Or `if ["a", "e", "i"].contains(string[string.startIndex]) { ... }`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750139/how-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values-swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift cannot infer the logic you are trying to make. The logic to Swift becomes something like this:

`if(str.characters[str.startIndex] == "a" || "e" || "i")`

is equivalent to `if(<Boolean expression> || "e" || "i")`

is equivalent to `if(<Boolean expression> || <String expression> || String expression)`

An alternative solution can be:

`if(["a", "b", "c"].contains(str.characters[str.startIndex])){`

Answer (score 2):

You should write it like this:

```
else if(str.characters[str.startIndex] == "a" || str.characters[str.startIndex] == "e" || str.characters[str.startIndex] == "i")
```

You get the error, because the compiler tries to convert both "e" and "i" to type Bool.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using if else switch will be more efficient:

```
func beginsWithVowel(str: String) -> Bool {

    guard str.characters.count > 0 else {
        return false
    }

    switch str.characters[str.startIndex]{
        case "a","e","i","o","u": 
        return true

        default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you perform `"a" || "e" || "i"` you are comparing between the `strings`. Use this code:

```
if(str.characters[str.startIndex] == "a" 
    || str.characters[str.startIndex] == "e" 
    || str.characters[str.startIndex] == "i") {

    // Your Code...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The boolean OR operator `||` expects boolean expressions.

So you would have to write `EXPR == "a" || EXPR == "e" || EXPR == "i"` where `EXPR` is the expression to get the first character.

However there is an easier solution (code is Swift 4)

```
func beginsWithVowel(str: String) -> Bool {
    return "aeiou".contains(String(str.prefix(1)))
}
```

It considers also the empty string case.