# Compare multiple variables to the same expression

Tags: ios, swift, comparison-operators

I am trying to compare multiple variables to an expression, like so:

```
if 1 <= x && x <= 5 &&
    1 <= y && y <= 5 &&
    1 <= z && z <= 5 {
    // Code to run if true
}
```

I found a [question related to comparing a variable to multiple `specific` values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750139/how-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values-swift), which is not what I want because it is not a comparison in an inequality.

Is there any way I can shorten this, in any way?

For example making an inequality like `1 <= x && x <= 5` shortened, or making me able to compare `x`, `y`, and `z` easily in other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ranges!

```
if (1...5).contains(x) &&
   (1...5).contains(y) &&
   (1...5).contains(z) {

}
```

Alternatively, create a closure that checks whether something is in range:

```
let inRange: (Int) -> Bool = (1...5).contains
if inRange(x) && inRange(y) && inRange(z) {

}
```

As Hamish has suggested, the `allSatisfy` method in Swift 4.2 can be implemented as an extension like this:

```
extension Sequence {
    func allSatisfy(_ predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool {
        return try !contains { try !predicate($0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know you could do that! Thanks, this will work for me :)

Comment: In Swift 4.2, you could even say `if [x, y, z].allSatisfy((1...5).contains) {}` :)

Comment: @Hamish I can't find the method `allSatisfy`. Xcode 9.3.1 supports Swift 4.2 right?

Comment: @Sweeper No, Swift 4.1 ships with Xcode 9.3.1 – Swift 4.2 hasn't been officially released yet, but you can pick up a dev snapshot over at https://swift.org/download/#snapshots which you can plug into Xcode.

Comment: Though the implementation for `allSatisfy` is pretty simple, it could be easily added in a `Sequence` extension for 4.1 (and then removed once 4.2 comes around) – `func allSatisfy(_ predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool { return try !contains { try !predicate($0) } }`

Comment: @Hamish An answer for the future... haha. I will use that when it comes out, in the mean time I will try other ways

Comment: @George_E_2 You can use it now if you want. Just write the extension as Hamish has suggested!

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah that's what I am using for now

Answer (score 2):

Another option: match against a tuple of ranges:

```
if case (1...5, 1...5, 1...5) = (x, y, z) {

}
```

Or use a switch-statement to match against one or more
tuples of ranges:

```
switch (x, y, z) {
case (1...5, 1...5, 1...5):
    print("all between 1 and 5")

case (..<0, ..<0, ..<0):
    print("all negative")

default:
    break
}
```

(Compare [Can I use the range operator with if statement in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893110/can-i-use-the-range-operator-with-if-statement-in-swift).)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
if [x,y,z].compactMap{ (1...5).contains($0) }.contains(true) {
    //Do stuff
}
```