# How can I, in a if Statement ask for multiple possible numbers, Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, random, numbers

I want to ask if the generated random Number is 1 or 13 or 25. I cut ask something like:

```
if randomNumber == (1) || if randomNumber == (13) || if randomNumber == (25)
```

and that's works but its way to much code. I try to minimize my code.

I did try something like this:
`if randomNumber == (1 || 13 || 25)`
but this didn't worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare one value against multiple values - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750139/how-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert them to a simple collection like an `array` or something and use its methods like:

```
if [1, 13, 25].contains(randomNumber)
```

#### More generally:

```
if (<#myArray#>.contains { <#condition#> }
```